Is another interview required for SENTRI/Trusted Traveler renewal
We're a family of 6, and were able to interview together when we were first approved for the SENTRI / Trusted Traveler program.
If we are having to renew, will we be required to come in for another interview, or is it not required (unless they decide it is)?  Interviewing the first time wasn't painful as we were together, but since renewal falls on your birthday and not the date you were approved, we have a span of almost an entire year to get through the 6 of us.  Having 6 individual interviews would be annoying at the very least.
I now also have 3 adult (aged) children so that probably further complicates things...
We don't qualify for Global Entry, so looking for answers specific to SENTRI if possible.

According to the CBP:

Will I Need to Interview Again?
An interview may be required upon renewal. This is determined by the vetting center.

Unfortunately, vague as it is, I think this is the best possible answer. Sometimes they make people do interviews again, and sometimes they don't, using criteria they don't publish. Unfortunately, the only way to know for sure which bucket you will fall into is to try to renew and see what happens.
According to the same renewal FAQ page linked above, you can renew your membership up to one year before it expires, so one option for your family might be to renew all your memberships at around the time the earliest-to-expire one is expiring, if all the other memberships will be less than one year from expiry at that point. That way, any family members who do end up needing interviews will at least be able to do so at the same time.

That's what I thought I'd heard/seen somewhere but couldn't find it.  The renewal link in my Trusted Traveler just has the same info as if we were applying the first time.  Thanks

@Midavalo for what it's worth, I was told in the renewal process that an interview would be required, and then 48 hours later my renewal was approved with no interview. But obviously this can not be guaranteed for everyone.
